# pg_top not displaying colors in terminal

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I am looking to get pg_top to display colors

If I try toggling <kbd>C</kbd> while in pg_top, it does nothing to display colors

If I try to list the tags, I get nothing showing up under the `Top color settings` part

```
$ pg_top -d mydb -T
These color tags are available:
   1min 5min 15min header cpu.user cpu.nice cpu.system cpu.idle cpu.iowait
   memory.used memory.free memory.shared memory.buffers memory.cached swap.used
   swap.free swap.cached swap.in swap.out

Top color settings:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do this by fiddling with the `PG_TOPCOLORS` shell environment variable** (you can add it to your .bashrc):

```
export PG_TOPCOLORS="header=,#37:cpu.user=1,20#33:cpu.system=1,10#33:cpu.system=11,30#31
```

If you then run `pg_top -T` you can preview how the colors will look (just like in the screenshot below):

[image]

The way it works is that you can assign a color, *represented by a number*, to one or any combination of the following color tags (make sure there are no spaces and to separate with commas if you have multiple tags you are assigning colors to):

```
 1min 
 5min 
 15min 
 header 
 cpu.user 
 cpu.nice 
 cpu.system 
 cpu.idle 
 cpu.iowait
 memory.used 
 memory.free 
 memory.shared 
 memory.buffers 
 memory.cached 
 swap.used
 swap.free 
 swap.cached 
 swap.in 
 swap.out
```

The following is a list of the ansi color [codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3-bit_and_4-bit):

```
Number  Name    
30      Black   
31      Red     
32      Green   
33      Yellow  
34      Blue    
35      Magenta 
36      Cyan    
37      White   
90      Bright Black (Gray)
91      Bright Red
92      Bright Green
93      Bright Yellow
94      Bright Blue
95      Bright Magenta 
96      Bright Cyan
97      Bright White
```